# Fill all unallocated space with texture

Tags: unity

I have a system of bunkers underground, and I need to fill all the free space where there are no buildings - with earth. Yes, I can manually add a ground texture to the plane, but I have procedural level generation.

I thought there might be some kind of filter on the camera that I don't know about. Or maybe there are some other solutions?

[image]

Comment: If your levels are flat, you just need one large ground plane slightly below the rooms. You could also consider using a skybox, as they are specifically designed to fill empty space.

Comment: Does the earth visual need to be the same height of the ceiling? So that you get a nice effect when the camera moves around?

Comment: @liggiorgio yes, i whant exactly what you say